# Definition of dense set

Tags: definition, order-theory

Is this definition is correct?:

Let $\preceq$ an order in $A$, $B \subset A$, with $B \neq \emptyset $. Then $B$ is a dense set in $A$ if 
$$\forall x,y \in A  ( x \prec y \to \exists b \in B( x \prec b \prec y))$$

Thanks in advance!

P.S. $x \prec y$ means $x \preceq y \,\land\, x \neq y $ and  $B \subset A$ means $B \subseteq A \,\land\, A \neq B$.

Comment: Are you asking if this definition is correct?

Comment: @AviSteiner, yes!

Comment: @AviSteiner... thansk for corrections!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\preceq$ is a linear order, your definition is correct. If $\preceq$ is a partial order, your definition is probably correct, though there is another notion of dense subset of a partial order that is important in set theory: $B$ is dense in $A$ if for each $a\in A$ there is a $b\in B$ such that $b\preceq a$.

Comment: M.Scott, un linear order is not a total order, is correct?

Comment: @Soviet: *Linear order* is another term for *total order*; they mean the same thing. I’m more accustomed to the term *linear order*, so I usually use it.

Comment: M.Scott,. okok I'm reading http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/linear+order#definitions_6 and http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/total+order#definitions_6

Comment: @Soviet: For some reason they choose to limit the term *linear order* to what I would call a *strict linear order*; they use *total order* for what I would call simply a linear order or, if there were any possibility of confusion, a *non-strict linear order*.

Comment: okok I understand....thanks soo much!!

Comment: @Soviet: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order), your definition is correct.