# Order-Dense Set Definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

The usual definitions of order-dense set I've seen are:

(1) Let $\precsim$ be an order defined on set $X$. $(X,\precsim)$ is order-dense if $\forall x,y \in X: x \precsim y, \exists z \in X: x \precsim z \precsim y$ ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order#cite_note-1), [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478033/a-problem-with-order-dense-set-definition)).

(2) Let $\precsim$ be an order defined on set $X$. $(X,\precsim)$ is order-dense if $\forall x,y \in X: x \prec y, \exists z \in X: x \precsim z \prec y$ (some lecture notes).

(3) Let $\precsim$ be an order defined on set $X$. $(X,\precsim)$ is order-dense if $\forall x,y \in X: x \prec y, \exists z \in X: x \prec z \prec y$ ([proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Close_Packed), [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471398/definition-of-dense-set)).

where $\precsim$ is a weak partial or total order and $\prec$ denotes the strict version of it.

Although similar, these are quite different. In sum, some definitions require some or all relations between the elements to be strict ($\prec$ instead of $\precsim$) and others even specify that $z \in X \backslash \{x,y\}$.

**Is there a consensual definition of an order-dense set?**

- Can $z \in X$ or has to be distinct from $x,y$, i.e. $z \in X \backslash \{x,y\}$?
- Can $x\precsim z \precsim  y$ or has to be $x\prec z \prec y$?

(This is not trivial, as (1) holds trivially for any partially-ordered set; (2) and (3) prevent $X$ to be a singleton and, requiring $z \in X \backslash \{x,y\}$, would prevent $(\mathbb{N},\leq)$ to be order-dense in itself)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The wikipedia uses (3) but not (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both (1) and (2) taking $x=z$ will satisfy the conclusion, making *every* order a dense order. Unless we require that $z\notin\{x,y\}$, or a condition which implies that like $x\prec z\prec y$, there is no way to guarantee that some orders will not be dense.

While it is somewhat unusual for a singleton to be a "dense set", the definition does make sense if you only require that when $x\prec y$, then there is some $z$ such that $x\prec z\prec y$. Therefore often you should also require that for every $x$ there is some $y$ such that $x\prec y$ or $y\prec x$. Otherwise taking a discrete ordering will be dense vacuously.

Comment: If I interpret you correctly, then the definition should include either $z \notin \{x,y\}$ or $x \prec z \prec y$?
But which (given that the second condition is much stronger than the first if we allow for $x \precsim z \precsim y$)?

Comment: Allowing weak equality *and* requiring that $z\notin\{x,y\}$ is the same as requiring $x\prec z\prec y$.

Comment: I was thinking that we could have $\forall x,y \in X$, $x \precsim y$ and $y \precsim x$ and allowing for $z \in X\backslash \{x,y\}$ satisfying the first and not the second, so that the two conditions would not, in general, be the same. Am I thinking wrong? Edit: I am. I'm thinking about preorders and not orders. I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The only reasonable way to define a dense preorder is to require that the induced partial order (taking a quotient by the obvious equivalence relation).

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should differentiate between a dense order relation and a dense subset of an ordered set.

The order relation is dense when (3) holds.

A $Y$ is dense in an ordered set $(X,≾)$ iff a modified condition (1) holds:
\begin{equation}
∀x,y∈X:x≺y,∃z∈Y:x≾z≾y
\end{equation}
This reads: There are two sets: One set $X$ which provides order relation and works as the universe, here. And another set $Y$ which has a nonempty intersection with every closed order interval. This is more or less a relational description of the same idea which is behind the notion of a dense set in topology: Every element of $X$ has sufficiently many elements of $Y$ nearby. Or in other words $Y$ may not be the full set $X$, but $Y$ is a sufficiently close approximation of $X$ in some setting. And yes, $X$ should be dense in $X$ in this sense.

Comment: A slight modification for partial order $\precsim$: $\forall x,y\in X: x\prec y, \exists z \in Y: x\precsim z \precsim y$. $x$, $y$ should be distinct elements in $X$ to avoid the case $x=y\in X/Y$. When $x=y\in X/Y$, $x\succsim y$ is true (by reflexivity) but $\nexists z\in Y$, s.t. $x\precsim z \precsim y$ (by transitivity and anti-symmetry).

Comment: @HanWang you are right. I fixed the answer.