# Countable order-dense subset in a linear order

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

I ended up posting an answer to my own question, and I believe I knew this answer before I posted this question, but forgot about it.  At any rate, here it is for the record.

My question is inspired by the following one by @lu_sin. [Is there a countable order-dense family of open subsets of $(0,1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3306543)
While I answered the above question (and my answer was accepted), the question remains open under a slightly different definition of order-dense, as indicated in the comments over there. While trying to answer the modified version of the question (which I believe ought to have something to do with $(0,1)$ being hereditarily Lindelöf and hereditarily separable), I came up with the following question.

Let $(X,<)$ be a linear (same as total) order. Assume that:

$(*)\ \ \ $  $X$ has no uncountable well-ordered subset (under the order induced by $<$), and no uncountable reverse well-ordered subset.

Call a set $D\subseteq X$ order-dense in $X$ if whenever $\{x,y\}\subseteq X$ with $x<y$ then there is $z\in D$ such that $x\le z\le y$. (Note that under this definition the integers are order-dense in themselves, which would not be the case if we required that $x<z<y$. In that other question I find the version with $\le$ more difficult to answer, which is the reason I use $\le$ here.)

**Question**. Assuming condition $(*)$ as above, is there a countable set $C$ which is order-dense in $X$?

I could answer it under a certain "local" assumption, as explained below (but I think this assumption makes the answer rather easy, and I do not know the answer in general). 
(On third reading I realized that I have a gap in the construction below, but I will leave  it as is for now, perhaps it illustrates some of the ideas I was thinking about.)

Call an $x\in X$ $r$-good (for right-good) if either (a) $x=\max X$ (if it exists), or (b) there is $x^+>x$ and a countable set $D=D(x,x^+)$ that is order-dense in $[x,x^+]$. Analogously, call an $x\in X$ $l$-good if either (a) $x=\min X$ (if it exists), or (b) there is $x^-<x$ and a countable set $D=D(x^-,x)$ that is order-dense in $[x^-,x]$. If each $x$ in $X$ is good (i.e. both $r$-good and $l$-good) then the answer to the above question is yes. 
Indeed starting with any $x_0\in X$ we could get an increasing countable transfinite sequence 
$S=\{x_\alpha:\alpha<\gamma\}$ for some $0<\gamma<\omega_1$ such that $\sup S=\sup X$, and for each $\alpha$ there is a countable $D_\alpha$ order-dense in $[x_\alpha,x_{\alpha+1}]$ (except only if $x_\alpha=\max X$). Similarly, there 
is a decreasing countable transfinite sequence $T=\{y_\alpha:\alpha<\delta\}$ for some $0<\delta<\omega_1$ such that $\inf T=\inf X$, $y_0=x_0$, and for each $\alpha<\delta$ there is a countable $C_\alpha$ order-dense in $[y_{\alpha+1},y_\alpha]$ (unless $y_\alpha=\min X$). Then we could let $C$ to be the union of all $D_\alpha,\alpha<\gamma$, and 
all $C_\alpha,\alpha<\delta$ (also throw in $S$ and $T$ and the endpoints of $X$, if any). 
There is a gap in the above argument, I was implicitly assuming that if $\alpha>0$ is limit then $x_\alpha=\sup_{\beta<\alpha}x_\beta$ 
(and similarly $y_\alpha=\inf_{\beta<\alpha}y_\beta$.) If
$\alpha>0$ is limit and $\sup_{\beta<\alpha}x_\beta$ is a gap of $X$ (i.e. $\sup_{\beta<\alpha}x_\beta$ does not exist in $X$ because $X$ is not complete) then I do not know how I want to define $x_\alpha$.

The answer is likely to be known, I would be grateful for a reference too.

Extra comments on condition $(*)$. 
For the record, condition $(*)$ was first stated as follows. 
For every $Y\subseteq X$ there is a countable (finite allowed) $Z\subseteq Y$ such that $\sup Y=\sup Z$ and there is a countable $W\subseteq Y$ such that $\inf Y=\inf W$. (Note that we may replace $Z$ with $Z\cup W$ and require, equivalently, that for every $Y\subseteq X$ there is a countable $Z\subseteq Y$ such that $\sup Y=\sup Z$ and $\inf Y=\inf Z$.) It seems we could drop the requirement that $Z\subseteq Y$ and $W\subseteq Y$. Just require that for every $Y\subseteq X$ there is a countable (finite allowed) $Z$ such that $\sup Y=\sup Z$ and there is a countable $W$ such that $\inf Y=\inf W$. Then I edited it as I realized: 
I may have made things more complicated than necessary, will think, perhaps I should have just said that $X$ has no subset that is order-isomorphic to $\omega_1$, or reverse order-isomorphic to $\omega_1$.

One example of a set that satisfies condition $(*)$ is the open unit interval $(0,1)$ with the usual order $\le$.

Another example (related to the question that was linked): If $X=\mathcal V$ where $\mathcal V$ is a nested collection of open subsets of $(0,1)$ (i.e. a linear order under set-inclusion), then $\mathcal V$ satisfies condition $(*)$, which could be shown (I believe) using that $(0,1)$ is hereditarily Lindelöf and hereditarily separable.

I realize I could have stated my question in yet another different, and apparently more general way (closer to the statement of the linked question). Suppose $P$ is a partial order and $X$ is a subset which is a chain, i.e. a linear order (under the induced order from $P$). Call a set $D\subseteq P$ dense in $X$ (where we do not require that $D\subseteq X$) if whenever $\{x,y\}\subseteq X$ with $x<y$ then there is $z\in D$ such that $x\le z\le y$. Question. If $X$ satisfies condition 
$(*)$ above, is there a countable set $C\subseteq P$ which is order-dense in $X$ (where we do not require that $C\subseteq X$)?
I tend to believe that the two versions of the question are equivalent, but did not attempt to verify all details.

Here is a related example, let $\mathcal V=\{(-x,x):0<x<1\}$, a nested collection of open sets in $(-1,1)$. Let $D=\{(-r,r):0<r<1, \ r\in\Bbb Q\}$, where $\Bbb Q$ denotes the rational numbers. Then $D$ is countable and order-dense in $\mathcal V$ (under either definition).

This question is such a mess ... I feel like I have not done my homework, but I will leave it as is for now, perhaps come back to it later.

Comment: The answer is no. See Exercise 32 Chapter 2 of Kunen's 1980 book or just google Aronszajn line.

Comment: @hot_queen Thank you, I will take a look (don't even remember the def of Aronszajn line at the moment). I think the lex ordered square also provides an example (perhaps more easily described, though Aronszajn line is also a standard example for people who work).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hassle the problem per se, consider simply the upper portion.

Let S be a complete linear order.
Assume for all A subset S,
exists countable B subset A with sup A = sup B.
Is there a countable, weakly order dense subset of S?

Is the existence of such a set equivalent to
for all A subset S, A is not order isomorphic to $\omega_1$?

D is weakly order dense, when
for all a,b in S, (a < b implies exists x in D with a <= x <= b).

Assume S is a complete linear order let A be order isomorphic to $\omega_1$.
Then A subset S does not have the property
exists countable subset B, sup A = sup B.
Thus, the nonexistence of such a set is not equivalent to a weakly order dense subset of S + the assumptions for S, but a result of those assumptions.

Comment: thank you for trying to help. I got completely entangled in what I am trying to ask. I do not quite follow the last sentence in your answer, what are you aiming at. I posted an answer (to my own question) and the linear order there is complete (only except it has no first and last element, but we could add $\{0\}$ and $(-1,1)$ if we insist on a first and last element).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think the answer is no, and is rather easy (in the generality in which I asked the question), and I knew it when I tried to answer that other linked question but forgot about it :). I do not know what I want to do of this question, feels like there ought to be a better version of the question where the answer might be interesting.

So here is my attempted answer.

Let $X=\{(-x,x):0<x<1\}\cup\{[-x,x]:0<x<1\}$. Notice this is a linear order under set-inclusion. Condition $(*)$ is easy to verify (boils down to using that $(0,1)$ with $\le$ has no uncountable well-ordered, or uncountable reverse well-ordered subset). 
Yet, if $D\subseteq X$ is a set which is order-dense in $X$ (and which apparently I should call weakly order-dense, as in the answer by @WilliamElliot) then, for each $x$, either $(-x,x)$ or $[-x,x]$ (or both) must be in $D$, showing that $D$ must necessarily have the cardinality of the continuum.

Copied/edited from @WilliamElliot's answer:
Definition. $D$ is weakly order-dense in $X$ if for all $x,y$ in $X$ with $x<y$ there is $z\in D$ such that $x\le z\le y$.

This just makes the linked question of @lu_sin more interesting to me (in its version about weakly order-dense, i.e when, in that question, we only require $V \subseteq U \subseteq V'$ instead of $V \subsetneq U \subsetneq V'$). The linear order there consists of open sets only (open subsets of $(0,1)$ ordered by set inclusion). [Is there a countable order-dense family of open subsets of $(0,1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3306543)

Comment: it may look like I am tinkering with the wrong definition of order-dense, using non-strict inequalities (e.g. see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1922761 and the answer by @Asaf there why the definition with strict inequalities would make most sense), yet it puzzles me that the linked question seems more difficult to answer if we use the "wrong" definition. This, despite that both the original linked question, and my own question here have rather trivial answers. A chain of open subsets of $(0,1)$ with $\subseteq$ seems a more difficult linear order to work with, or I am overlooking something

Comment: Another answer is provided by the unit square with the lex order. It satisfies $(*)$, but any order-dense subset must have cardinality continuum. (Here we could insist on strict inequalities in the definition of order-dense, either way the answer is the same.)

Comment: Your order is order isomorphic to R×{0,1} in dictionary order.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yes, thank you! Indeed, we get an order-isomorphism $\psi:X\to Y$ here $X$ is as in my answer and $Y$ is $(0,1)\times\{0,1\}$ with the dictionary (i.e. lexicographic) order by $\psi((-x,x))=\langle x,0\rangle$ and $\psi([-x,x])=\langle x,1\rangle$. Clearly $Y$ in turn is order isomorphic to $\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}$ (in dictionary order) since $(0,1)$ is order isomorphic to $\Bbb R$. I wouldn't have noticed this if it wasn't for your message.